# list with a fragment?

Tags: android, list, android-fragments

What is the paradigm to have ListView next to some other fragment in Android?

Now we have the wide screen tablets, I want to update my code to add a Fragment next to the ListView.

How do you do that, in outline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Probably use a `ListFragment` for the list, though I think that this is not strictly required.

Step #2: Have a space in your layout for the fragment you want to add.

Step #3: Use `FragmentManager` and a `FragmentTransaction` to add the fragment.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I don't have any XML referring to the ListView as a whole.   Just the xml for a list item.   Without XML for the List as a whole I don't have XML to add it to a LinearLayout (etc) next to the fragment.    I have all the working code for the list (from a colleague) and I'm asking myself "what's the least intrusive code to add so that I can layout this list next to this fragment?"    Thanks, Mark.

Comment: @Peter vdL: "The issue I'm having is that I don't have any XML referring to the ListView as a whole." -- then you have a problem. If you do not have the `ListView` or the `ListFragment`, you cannot put anything alongside of it. This is no different than with any other `View` (or `View`-like thingy). The "least intrusive code" is probably a rewrite of the UI definition, so you get a layout file to work with. Get your colleague to do it. :-)

Comment: You can always create a layout file that is just a ListView tag at the root, with an android:id of @android:id/list. I've done that before.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544602/set-webview-loadurl-programmatically-that-is-in-fragment-class

Answer (score 0):

you can use the android documentation as an approch : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html