# Set WebView loadUrl programmatically that is in fragment class

Tags: android

What I need to achieve is that in every Tab I want to display different websites, like

```
Tab 1: http://www.stackoverflow.com
Tab 2: http://www.google..com
Tab 3. http://www.developers.android.com
```

My problem is I can't access the WebView object to a loadUrl()

To clarify my question here's my code:

**FragmentTabsPagerActivity.java**

```
    public class FragmentTabsPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

        private TabHost mTabHost;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, FragmentTabsPagerActivity.TabInfo>();
        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        ...

        private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
            mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup();

            TabInfo tabInfo = null;
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
            Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();

            bundle1.putInt("id", 1);
            bundle2.putInt("id", 2);
            bundle3.putInt("id", 3);

            FragmentTabsPagerActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", TabsFragment.class, bundle1)));
            FragmentTabsPagerActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", TabsFragment.class, bundle2)));
            FragmentTabsPagerActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", TabsFragment.class, bundle3)));

            this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        }
}
```

**TabsFragment.java**

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment{
    LinearLayout layout;
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings setting =mWebView.getSettings();

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        if(container == null){
            return null;
        }

        return layout;
        }

        public void setWebUrl(String url){
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**fragments_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you used LinearLayout as parent layout in fragments_layout xml

Comment: @NixitPatel, Hi! I added the code of fragments_layout check for my Edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. I made the my Tab dynamic using the code below.

In my **TabsFragment.java** I add an **id** and get set **id** by `id = getArguments().getInt("id");`

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment{
    LinearLayout layout;
    WebView mWebView;
    int id;

    public static TabsFragment newInstance(int id){
        TabsFragment tab = new TabsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", id);
        tab.setArguments(args);

        return tab;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings setting =mWebView.getSettings();

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        if(container == null){
            return null;
        }

        return layout;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            id = savedInstanceState.getInt("id");
        }else{
            id = getArguments().getInt("id");
        }

        Log.w("id", id+"");

        switch (id) {
        case 1:
            setWebUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            break;
        case 3:
            setWebUrl("http://www.google..com");
            break;
        case 2:
            setWebUrl("http://www.developers.android.com");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setWebUrl(String url){
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

And in **PagerAdapter.java** **method getItem(int position)** I create a new instance of **TabsFragment** class and return the new instance.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabsFragment tab = TabsFragment.newInstance(position+1);

        //return this.fragments.get(position);
        return tab;
    }
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem I think is in this line

```
layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout, container, false);
```

you are casting whole view layout in `LinearLayout`instead  do something like this...

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout, container, false);
mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
...
return v
```

hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

Why you must use Tab?   can't you use button instead?

click on different button, you use webview to load correspond pages.

You should know, It's really bad for you to new three webviews in you app.